# Is there a way to remove admin rights from a user and immediately apply this in powershell without relogging the user?

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently I have the problem that I remove some user from the local admin group over powershell but this user has still admin-rights for the whole session until he is forced to restart/login again.
I want to remove the admin-rights of the user as soon as I start my powershell script without the user to restart or login again.

My idea was maybe I could [change the account type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjObs.png) instead of removing him from the local admin group but I haven't found much on powershell comands for this if there is any.

Only this but I don't think that is what I am looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-user?view=exchange-ps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1

This is the command I used before:
`Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group Administratoren -Member $username -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: You can make all the changes you want, but the users session token will still have the administrator privileges for the local system. You need to terminate the logon session and have them log in again

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So there is no way to remove the admin privileges during a session? The problem is that I am not quite sure if it's a good idea to force restart the coputer after I removed the user from the group. Maybe someone is working on something and all the progress could be lost.

Comment: You can always send them a message as well as a timeout before restarting their computer :) look at `shutdown /r /t <time> /m \\computerName /c <your message here>`